# Is it better to get values from array or declaring them each time?

Tags: php, arrays

Example 1:

```
$a = 'value1';
$b = 'value2';
$c = 'value3';

$x = 'value1';
$y = 'value2';
$z = 'value3';
```

Example 2:

```
$var = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

$a = var[0];
$b = var[1];
$c = var[2];

$x = var[0];
$y = var[1];
$z = var[2];
```

Which example has less server resource usage? Which example is faster?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/FCgui / https://3v4l.org/F7abR

Comment: @Federkun straightforward and cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your neither has any impact on speed as it is trivial. If we talk about memory usage, then array uses more as it stores the same variables + reffence links (again, trivial but that is how it works). But there as other factors that you need to consider:

1.Readability - if you use array approach you code will be very dificult to trace especially in bigger functions.

2.Operations - if you use array array approach your operations with variables will be limited as things like += will break the array refference and store the values directly in variable.

3.Relations with other devs - if you use the array approach anyone else that has to work with your code will be spilling curses your way ;)